# Something similar to .net panels in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I apologize for yet, another beginner question. I have a .Net background and this is my first time with Android.

In .Net I could use panels to show/hide controls, and I'm looking to do the samething in Android.

This is what I'm trying to do: There will be two radio buttons on the top: Basic and Advanced. Depending on the radio button clicked, I want to show the relevant form. How can I possibly accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use setvisibility for the view
you have to register for CheckedChangeListener using setOnCheckedChangeListener for the radiogroup
In the onCheckedChanged
you have to do

hidingView.setVisibiliity(View.GONE)
showingview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Comment: But I have multiple views. Is there a view I can wrap all these in? like a panel of some kind. I tried putting in a View, but it gave me this error: android.view.View cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Comment: the xml is huge, but I'll try to create a map: linear -> scroll view -> linear -> view -> textviews and edittexts

Comment: 1. LinearLayout A) radiogroup (radiobutton1 , radio button2) B)Layout1  C) Layout2 . You could have a structure like this. and then show/ hide Layout1 and Layout2 depending upon radiobuttons

Comment: ohh I see...Layout1 and Layout2 can be linearlayout and I can give them an id...Thanks, I'll give that a try...!

Answer (score 0):

You could just put each one of your forms into its own FrameLayout and then use a conditional statement that checks for the state of the radio buttons. I dont know what kind of format your forms are in but Im imagining theyre probably a series of edittext boxes and TextViews. It would probably be easiest if you set it up your xml layout, declare the view to place one form and then add the other forms content to the FrameLayout dynamically in java according to the radio buttons pressed.

Comment: When you say panel do you mean an overall view to hold all your other views?

Comment: yeh...Basically I want to have a view, in which I have some textviews and edittexts, and should only show when radio button is clicked...